# Delphi: frame+colorbox=bug

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tframe

**Delphi XE** (It works fine in **Delphi 2010**).

Try: create a **frame** and a color box inside it. The color box -> set a **Selected color other than black and a style = cbCustomColor** (not cbCustomColors); paste the frame into the form, save a project.

Close the project. Reopen->errors as below:

[image]
[image]

I need this "custom color", who is freaking: me, a color box, a frame or whole Delphi? :)
Thanks!!!

Source code:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 202
  ClientWidth = 447
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  inline Frame21: TFrame2
    Left = 72
    Top = -38
    Width = 320
    Height = 240
    TabOrder = 0
    ExplicitLeft = 72
    ExplicitTop = -38
  end
end

unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Frame21: TFrame2;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.

object Frame2: TFrame2
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 320
  Height = 240
  TabOrder = 0
  object ColorBox1: TColorBox
    Left = 72
    Top = 48
    Width = 145
    Height = 22
    Selected = clGreen
    Style = [cbStandardColors, cbExtendedColors, cbSystemColors, cbCustomColor]
    TabOrder = 0
  end
end


unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, 
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  TFrame2 = class(TFrame)
    ColorBox1: TColorBox;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Delphi XE. Please add this to the [QC bug reporting system at Embarcadero](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx).

Comment: If someone wants to report - please report. I don't want, I am lazy (I'm not a professional programmer so this is not my priority) :)

Comment: I am not a professional programmer either, but I do report. It helps you and others. A bug not reported has a much worse chance of ever being solved.

Comment: @ Rudy Velthuis, Right! Please report!

Comment: @maxfax If it's not a priority why ask Rudy to report it? If you don't care about the bug why ask the question here? A QC report takes 5 minutes to submit.

Comment: @David Heffernan, it could be not a bug but my mistake. I did not ask Rudy, if he wants to do it...My English isn't at the top to report:)

Comment: @maxfax I take Jeroen's answer as confirmation that it is a bug. In fact, any time the IDE raises an AV dialog I would regard that as a bug no matter what the input.

Comment: I'd rather have the person that find a bug post a bug report; credit where credit is due.